# Initial conditions for a massive objects to follow a path

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, simulations

Suppose I have a path, such as the one traced out by $r^2 = \cos(2\theta)$, and $n$ objects with mass $m$ at equidistant points on this path. What velocities should each object initially have in order for the objects to trace out this path as they move subject only to mutual gravitational attraction? Clearly, it is not always possible for every possible path, so what conditions must a path have in order for this to work?

For a circular path, this is easy. Simply calculate the gravitational force from each object, equate this to the centripetal force, and solve for the velocity.

However, for a more general path, thing's get more complicated. My temptation is to approximate the curve a circle of radius $\frac{1}{\kappa}$ (where $\kappa$ is the curvature) and proceed as with the circle, but there are two possible issues:

1. The force won't necessarily be normal to the curve.
2. The curvature might be $0$ (for example, in the curve $r^2 = \cos(2\theta)$, the curvature is $0$ at the center.

Is it only possible on curves where neither of these problems occur? I don't think that is the case, because I've seen simulations in which objects orbit in the shape of a lemniscate. Therefore, these problems must have some resolution. Is it my method or my execution that is wrong, and how can I fix them?

Comment: Only a few very special paths allow this, see for instance: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/N-body_choreographies The three body problem is hard... the N body problem is even worse...